# Error al tratar de ingresar PASSWORD ALEATORIO

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, formularios, php7

Tengo un formulario de registro de usuarios en PHP conectado a mi base de datos en MYSQL, pero necesito que la contraseña se genere aleatoriamente y se inserte al campo de mi base de datos en dónde también tengo los demás campos insertados por el método post que son los que el usuario si registra, pero al tratar de hacer esto no logro insertarlos. AGRADEZCO SU AYUDA.

```
<?php

require 'funcs/conexion.php';

$nombreEmpresa = $_POST['nombre'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$numeroempleados = $_POST['numeroempleados'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$categorias = isset($_POST['categorias']) ? $_POST['categorias'] : null;

$arrayCategorias = null;

$num_array = count($categorias);
$contador = 0;

if($num_array>0){
foreach ($categorias as $key => $value) {
    if ($contador != $num_array-1){
        $arrayCategorias .= $value.' ';
        $contador++;
    } else {
        $arrayCategorias .= $value;
    }
}
}
//CREACIÓN DE CONTRASEÑA ALEATORIA
$caracteres = '123ANBCF';
for($x = 0; $x < 1; $x++){
$password = substr(str_shuffle($caracteres), 0, 6);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO empresasregistradas (nombreEmpresa, usuario, email, 
password, numEmpleados, categoria, estado) VALUES ('$nombreEmpresa', 
'$usuario', '$email', '$password' '$numeroempleados', '$arrayCategorias', 
'$estado')";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql); 

?>
```

Comment: ¿Se genera algún error?

Comment: Sólo me manda el mensaje de error del else y no registra nada...

Comment: Era una miserable coma, ustedes me dirán dónde no la puse o no analizaron tampoco el código como yo :v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trata esto :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO empresasregistradas (nombreEmpresa, usuario, email, 
password, numEmpleados, categoria, estado) VALUES ('$nombreEmpresa', 
'$usuario', '$email', '$password' '$numeroempleados', '$arrayCategorias', 
'$estado')";

Poner una coma entre `'$password' '$numeroempleados',`
```

Comment: GRACIAS EN REALIDAD ESE ERA EL ERROR

Answer (score 0):

```
$characteres                    = '123ANBCF';
$charactersLength               = strlen($characteres);
#itero 7 veces que sería la longitud de mi contraseña. aqui sería la que tú necesites.
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {

    $password               .= $characteres[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];

}
```